# ansible. Run handler on specific host

Tags: ansible, ansible-handlers

I need to collect some information during run of ansible and print this information in the end.

I've tried to define empty list variable in role. I added in playbook handler which add new value to list ant print value of this variable in the end of playbook.

```
  set_fact:
    manual_tasks: "{{ manual_tasks + ['restart apache'] }}"
```

I miss that set_fact host related. So this solution stop working as soon as I start using different hosts. Delegate_to is not solve problem as well. Is there way to make this list global? Or any other solution exist?

Answer (score 0):

Q: *`Add new value to list and print it at the end of the playbook. Is there way to make this list global?`*

A: No. It is not. "[Global](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables) scope is set by config, environment variables and the command line." A host can't *set_fact* in the play or global scope.

You might want to take a look at [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner). See [Sending Runner Status and Events to External Systems](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/external_interface.html#sending-runner-status-and-events-to-external-systems).